# Why does $("a:focus").length evaluate to 0 unless wrapped in setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, onblur, onfocus

I'm adding keyboard navigation to the main menu on my site, and I want any open submenus to close when the user tabs outside of the main menu. So I have the following function:

```
var $nav = $(".navigation nav.main"),
    $navItems = $nav.find("a");

$navItems.on("blur", function() {
    if ($nav.find("a:focus").length === 0) {
        closeMenu();
    }
});
```

The way that I would expect this to work is like this:

1. Whenever any link within the menu loses focus...
2. If there are *no* links within the menu that have focus, close the menu

But what actually happens is `$(nav.find("a:focus").length)` *always* evaluates to `0`, even when I can see directly on screen that there is indeed a link with focus within the menu.

However, if I wrap a `setTimeout()` around the conditional, then it works how I would expect:

```
var $nav = $(".navigation nav.main"),
    $navItems = $nav.find("a");

$navItems.on("blur", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ($nav.find("a:focus").length === 0) {
            closeMenu();
        }
    });
});
```

Now, `$nav.find("a:focus").length` evalulates to `1` every time I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, until I tab outside of the menu, at which point it evaluates to `0` and closes it.

This is exactly how I want it to work, but why is the `setTimeout()` necessary?

Comment: because of the ordering of events. blur happens before the next focus

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn nope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why doesn't it work?

As epascarello points out in the comments, your `blur` is happening before the next element has focus.

> Why does `setTimeout()`, even with a `0ms` delay, work?

I *believe* this has to do with the rendering engine. When you do a `setTimeout()`, the function gets "queued" *behind* the rendering engine's UI update (which focuses the next element). Despite there being no difference in *time*, the `setTimeout()` ensures the check happens *after* the UI update.

Order of events:

```
1. Fire blur event
2. Update UI
```

Order of events with a `setTimeout()`:

```
1. Fire blur event (queue new function) ──┐
2. Update UI                              |
3. Run the queued function    <───────────┘
```

> Is there an alternative?

The `blur` event's  [`relatedTarget`](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-type-blur) indicates which element will be receiving focus.

By knowing the element that's about to receive focus, you could use jQuery's [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to determine if it's a nav item or not.

```js
var $nav = $(".navigation nav.main"),
    $navItems = $nav.find("a");

$navItems.on("blur", function(e) {
  var $focusedElement = $(e.relatedTarget);
  var isNavItem = !!$navItems.filter($focusedElement).length;
  if (!isNavItem)
    console.log("The focused element is not a nav item.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation">
  <nav class="main">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </nav>
</div>

<a href="#">Non-nav link</a>
```